# How do I add a more/less link in block?

Tags: 7, blocks, search

How do I add a more/less link to drop-down and roll up a block?

I have a custom search block with a lot of field items and as such, the block is so long.
I want to be able to add a more link to drop down the redundant fields and less to roll up the block again.

I'm trying to do something similar to the search block on [checki.com.ng](http://checki.com.ng). I am running a Drupal 7 site, [naijabooker.com](http://naijabooker.com).

Comment: I think collapsible jquery can help you. Just add a reference to your template for the collapsible jquery and put css classes on the sections where you need it. See drupal_add_js() function and http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

Comment: For block hooks see, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7

Comment: can u pls break it down am still new to drupal

Comment: Ill put it here once I get home but you may want to try this module for quicker results for you: http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion

Comment: You may put the collapsible.js file from your theme.info file, as is, scripts[] = collaspible.js and then add the jquery code for collapsible with reference to this document http://drupal.org/node/171213. I hope you know where to put the codes though.

Comment: more info for your study here http://drupal.org/node/1258792, sorry I could not give you concrete sample. Will try though and present you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a custom block with a form created from your custom module.
You would need to add an attribute `#prefix` to the first field item starting from which you want to hide the items and add an attribute `#suffix` to the last field item you want to hide, For example,

```
$form['first_item']['#prefix'] = '<div id="accordian">';

// more elements here

$form['last_item']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Then, you can bind `jQuery.slideUp()` and `jQuery.slideDown()` to the more/less link element, let's say for example, `#moreless`.

```
$('#moreless').bind('click', function(){ 
    if( $('#accordian:visible').size() ){
         $('#accordian').slideUp();
         $(this).html('More &raquo;');
     }else{
         $('#accordian').slideDown();
         $(this).html('Less &laquo;');
     }
}​);​
```

You can see the working jQuery code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9khMM/). These two jQuery functions are provided by jQuery core API. You don't need to include any extra library.